# UISrcollView in IOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I created a `UIScrollView` with some images. And I made a touch dragging on `UIImageView` - drag to the next page when we touch it.
I used `viewDidAppear` to scroll till the end of `UIScrollView` :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1400);
}
```

But when I used `Swipe Gesture Recognizer` to drag back `UIScrollView`, I cant scroll to bottom like when begin run the app. How can I solve it ?

Comment: What I understood from your question is you need a paginated scroll view with images displaying on it. Assuming that its a vertical  scroll view and you can obtain that feature without using Swipe Gesture Recognizer(Pagination is a default feature in Scroll View). Can you please explain a bit more about your requirement?

Comment: In first ViewController I had a ScrollView include the images. When touch to a image, a new ViewController with content will appear. It's a over vertical scroll so I use viewDidAppear to able scroll to bottom. But when I swipe in a new ViewController back to ScrollView, I cant scroll to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly tell the gesture not to cancel the touches of its content view. Try this:

```
[swipe setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

If that doesn't do it, try using the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Put on first ViewController.m or target ViewController.m?

Comment: @TomKing Whichever class the gesture is added from.

Comment: I try the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method like your suggest but it not work

Comment: @TomKing Did you tell your class to conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, and see the delegate of the gesture to that class?

Comment: I have no idea about the thing you said. Can show me clearly ?

Comment: Sure thing, in your .h you need to be sure to include `< UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` and where you set up the gesture recognizer you need to include `[myGesture setDelegate:self];`.

Comment: Or I create a class,that implements UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol ?